# Can you play Minecraft with friends on different consoles?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

Can I play Minecraft with friends if I'm using Xbox 360 console and they are using a ps4 or are playing it in a phone?

Answer (score 1):

Sad news... the cross-play option is only available on the Xbox One, Mobile, Nintendo Switch, Windows 10 PCs and PS4s, because they are the only devices which can run Bedrock Edition Minecraft. The Xbox 360 is not included.

However, if you do want to cross-play on a 360, it must be done via Minecraft Realms.

Source: [Windows 10 and Xbox 360 Minecraft Crossplay?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/windows-10-and-xbox-360-minecraft-crossplay/15c75321-35d4-48cb-966a-0d580265c08b#:%7E:text=Cross%20play%20on%20Minecraft%20is,different%20version%20of%20the%20game.)

Comment: AFAIK there's an option for cross-play using Bedrock Edition clients on Java Edition server.  It will be limited as some BE options are unavailable on JE and vice versa, so only the "common denominator" features will work.